# Android Studio: Fail to parse SDK may be missing the directory add-ons

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I am new to android software development. When I try to write the first android program, a pop up window shows up after I finish choosing all the basic settings, said that it fail to parse SDK, and the directory 'add-ons' might be missing. I check the SDK folder I just install, and the SDK folder exist, also with plenty of stuff inside. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 52):

The SDK is bundled with Android Studio, you don't have to download it separately.

I've seen this issue on both machines I've installed Android Studio on - the "add-ons" directory doesn't get created at install.

Assuming you're on 64 bit Windows and installed to default location, look here:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk**

If you don't have a "Program Files (x86)" folder, look in "Program Files"

I'd bet there's no "add-ons" folder in there.  If not, create one and than start Android Studio.  You should see no problems.

Comment: The main reason why it does not work is because Android Studio does not have permission to create that folder (since it is located inside Program Files, just run Android Studio as Admin and you don't have to do all that hack.

Answer (score 6):

I ran Android Studio as Administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please check if you've actually downloaded the SDK with the SDK Manager.

Then:

- Close your current open project in order to get the welcome screen of the Android Studio (it's small window where you have your projects listed on the left side)
- Click on Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure
- Click on SDKs under Platform Settings: in the middle column you should see the list of the SDKs currently installed on your machine
- Click on Android SDK under Platform Settings and check/set the SDK location
- Apply any change and restart Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and yes the add-ons folder was not installed in sdk folder.

Create the folder add-ons in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk folder.

Then create the project again. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

On my ubuntu linux distribution, a "missing add-ons directory" problem was caused by folder permissions. The owner of the installed android-studio was root. And I encountered the problem when running android studio (version 0.3.2) as a regular user and creating for the very first time a new project. So, it seems that as part of creating the project, the add-ons directory is created. Although not desirable, I solved the problem by making this regular user the owner of the android-studio installation (using a chown -R command).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but solved :
I have installed package "Android studio for linux" in /usr/local/android-studio in it you will find /usr/local/android-studio/sdk/tools/android executable tool too download or update Android SDK.
Once done, retry to launch studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because my user is not an administrator in win7 and I installed Android Studios for everyone and not just for me. Therefore the SDK stuff was installed under Program Files(x86) which I don't have any write access to, instead of under your user in C:\Users\

To solve I had to either:

- Change write/modify permissions for *C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk* for your user. Then you don't have to run the Android studio as admin every time.
- Reinstall Android studio and choose to install it just for you (your user)
- Run the Android studio as Administrator which is bit annoying if you have a separate admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem like you and i have resolve that! You must take owner ship this folder SDK in folder's you setup android studio. You can download file Takeownership on link. install it just the way click on file TakeOwnerShip-install.reg and go to folder SKD, right click and select TakeOwnerShip. Done this problem will be resolve.
[TakeOwnerShip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/gvz5uoz311l93tn/AddTakeOwnershipOption.rar)

Comment: I don't like download links linking to random .rar archives. Can you include a link to the original project page of the tool?

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can edit this Code and save with format .reg and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]
@="Take ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Take ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
```

Answer (score -2):

update program to latest, android studio will active icon SDK Manager.
if you use old version icon SDK not active you must find SDK support it.