# The Android SDK may be missing the directory 'add-ons'

Tags: java, android, sdk, java-6

I installed android studio and JDK, and after create new project in android studio I see this alert:

```
Cause: failed to parse SDK!<br>
The Android SDK may be missing the directory 'add-ons'.<br>
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

This is path to my android SDK

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk**

And this to my java JDK

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45** (this I put in JAVA_HOME in environment variables)

Why I cant create new project? Always show me the alert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772252/android-studio-fail-to-parse-sdk-may-be-missing-the-directory-add-ons

Comment: I don't understande this: I'd bet there's no "add-ons" folder in there. If not, create one and than start Android Studio. You should see no problems., what I have to create and where?

Comment: try to create an add-ons folder in your sdk folder

Comment: sorry for this simply question, but here is my path to android sdk C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk, and what folder I heve to create here?

Comment: @coelho Thank you very much i created folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk, and name of this new folder must be "add-ons" thank you very much